# jQuery - parent "this"

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

```
$('form').each(function(){
  var form = this;
  $('a', this).click(function(){ form.submit(); });
});
```

Is there any way I can get the parent (`this`) element inside of that click function, without using a intermediate variable? I was thinking that maybe there's a keyword I'm not aware of that lets you do it.

In the $.ajax function there's a `context` paramters which allows you to do something like this.

Comment: Could you not use `$('a', this).click(function(){ $(this).closest('form').submit(); });` Or...did you want a more concise/specific answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you have done it the best way. Convention suggests using that:

```
var that = this;
$('a', this).click(function(){ that.submit(); });
```

Comment: Or self.

    var self = this;

Comment: Personally, I dislike that convention. Using a descriptive name (like `form`) is far superior when it comes to reading the code.

Comment: This doesn't the question: `"...without using a intermediate variable"`

Comment: True, but I believe it's a better and safer solution than the others. Now Alex can see ways to do it and a strong recommendation that she keep it as is!

Answer (score 2):

since `a` is a child of `form`, you can use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest):

```
$('a', this).click(function(){ $(this).closest('form').submit(); });
```

Another option is [`proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy):

```
$('a', this).click($.proxy(function(){ this.submit(); }, this));
```

Comment: The only problem with using `$.proxy` is that you lose the ability to refer to the usual `this` reference within the event handler.

Comment: @user349433 - true, but you could also pass an event parameter and check the `target`. Either way I prefer `closest` in this scenario

Comment: I think it's a mistake to go to the DOM for this. Though it would be easy to debug, it'll break if the hierarchy changes and you're taxing the script by traversing again to an element you've already selected. Better to stay in abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

Sure -- use a closure.

```
$('form').each(function() {
  $('a', this).click((function(x) { return function() { x.submit(); })(this));
});
```

If you have a `curry` function (similar to the one in Prototype, not sure if one's built into jQuery), you can simplify that middle line a bit:

```
$('a', this).click(curry(function(x) { x.submit(); }, this));
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, your example is right, and secondly, it's how most people would do it. There is no keyword, just reversing direction and traversing the DOM for the most likely parent (which is silly since you've already found it, right?). That being the case, I'd recommend an intermediate variable, even if other answerer's have correctly shown how to use `closest`. (Also, it relies on somewhat of a technicality, that a `<form>` inside a `<form>` is invalid HTML. There's no guarantee for things like a `<div>` that it doesn't cross over any child `<div>`s looking for the next `<a>`.)

In jQuery you see a lot of stuff like this:

```
$("#parent").something(function() {

   var _this = this;
// var self = this;
// var that = this;
// var someMoreMeaningfulName = this;

   $("#child", this).somethingElse(function() {
      $(_this).somethingEvenElser();
      ...
   });
});
```

It's not the prettiest thing to read, but the pattern occurs frequently enough that it's easily recognizable. I somewhat recommend what you're doing (`var form`) instead of stuff like `_this` (underscore can imply private variables), `self` (it's actually not), etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to refer to it with jquery's parent (or parents depending on how nested the a tag is) selector

So something like this should work:

```
$('form').each(function(){
  $('a', $(this)).click(function(){ $(this).parent('form').submit(); });
});
```